# Why EBS keeps waiting for terminated instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, lifecycle

Why EBS keeps waiting for terminated instances?

> 2016-03-02 01:41:22 UTC+0100  INFO    Still waiting for the following 3
>   instances to become healthy: [i-1b5e9691, i-7f5c94f5, i-5d5e96d7].

Only one instance is still active and passes the load balancer health check, the others are already terminated a long time ago.

Can I fix this with a proper lifecycle or ebs health check?

My ec2 instance on load balancer passes the healthcheck on TCP port 80, but maybe ebs fails due to the document root config.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/lifecycle-hooks.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html

(Eventually the configuration rolled back).